# JAVA Generics and inheritance - passing parametrization type to subclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have had a look at other questions and cannot quite find the answer I am after, though I am pretty sure its a common problem and I am being dumb.

I have the following classes in Java:

```
public abstract class A<U extends User>{
    U user;

    public U getUser(){
        return user;
    }

    //methods and stuff
}
```

I then have:

```
public abstract class B<U extends User> extends A<U>{
    // some more methods and stuff
}
```

and finally I have

```
public class C extends B<SuperUser>{

}
```

I then have:

```
class SuperUser extends User{
}

class User {}
```

With this arrangement I get this error in C:

> The type B is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments SuperUser

and if I remove `<SuperUser>` from C I get a warning:

> B is a raw type. References to generic type B should be parameterized

So, please, what am I doing wrong? I am aiming at getting this code working without warnings/ unchecked casts etc.:

```
C myC = new C();
SuperUser user = myC.getUser();
```

Comment: Yeah, code compiles fin on Java 7.

Comment: This could happen if `B` were an inner class of `A`, instead of a stand-alone class.  Can you advise whether this is the case?

Comment: It compiles fine for me too.

Comment: The CRTP in Java? Thats possible?

Comment: For B, you first used a bounded type parameter then you passed a parameterized type: B<SuperUser>. Did you try the generic type: B<U>?

Comment: It's only bounded if `B` is inner to `A`; hence my comment.  But Jon has not yet replied.

Comment: Thanks all. Comments from @Sotirios Delimanolis and @ajb made me try it as standalone project...and in simplified form above does compile. Feel I have wasted people's time a little, should have done that first b4 asking. Code a simplification of more involved Android project involving libraries- `A` and `B` in Android library and `C` in the Android project proper. Using EclipseIDE something was not a fan of this arrangement. Good to know that my understanding of Generics ok, annoying could not get it to work in 'droid project. What now? Do I leave this question in S.O. or delete it?